# Why do we differentiate functions to show linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I recently came across something I haven't seen in some time and I am having trouble recalling the reason behind differentiation when showing that two functions are linearly independent.

**Example:** Suppose $V$ is a vector space of all functions over $\mathbb{R}$ of a variable $t$. Let $f_{1}(t) = te^{t}$ and $f_{2}(t) = e^{2t}$. Show that $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are linearly independent.

**Proof.** Suppose $\exists c_{1},c_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$c_{1}f_{1}(t)+c_{2}f_{2}(t) = 0$$

Then we obtain $c_{1}te^{t}+c_{2}e^{2t}=0$. Then, by differentiating with respect to $t$ we have the relation $c_{1}e^{t}(1+t)+c_{2}e^{2t}=0$. We can then divide each term by $e^t$ and we get the system

$$\lbrace{c_{1}t+c_{2}e^{t}=0, c_{1}(1+t)+c_{2}e^{t} = 0\rbrace}$$

The result of algebraic manipulation by Gauss-elimination is that $c_{1}=c_{2}=0$. Hence $f_{1},f_{2}$ are linearly independent functions. $\square$

This is a trivial example, but what I am caught up on is this: Why are we allowed to differentiate at all to come up with a secondary relation in order to solve the system of equations? What theorem am I missing and where can I find more information on this idea. The book I am reading (*Linear Algebra* by Serge Lang) simply glosses over this fact without any explanation. I don't generally like using results without there being concrete evidence or a proof.

A follow up question is this, do we differentiate $n-1$ times if we have $n$ real numbers in order to obtain the $n$ equations to solve?

**Question is resolved in the comments**

Comment: A function which is zero everywhere has derivative zero everywhere. Your equality is supposed to be true for all $t.$ If it was true for only one $t,$ you’d just have a function which is zero somewhere, and the derivative wouldn’t be allowed. But if zero everywhere, then the derivative is also zero everywhere.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Because $c_{1}f_{1}(t) + c_{2}f_{2}(t)$ is a new function in the space and all its derivatives are also functions in the space, for all $t$, we can utilize this to come up with $2$ distinct functions with real numbers $c_{1},c_{2}$ whose values must be zero if linearly indepedent?

Comment: (Of course, there is no reason to take the derivative in this example. If $c_1f_1(t)+c_2f_2(t)=0$ for all $t,$ then we can take $t=0$ and get $c_2=0,$ and then take $t=1$ and get $c_1=0.$)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that may be true and an obvious oversight, but what I am after is whether this generalized procedure works in the context of differentiation.

Comment: It has nothing to do with linear independence. If $f_1(f_2(t))=0,$ for all $t,$ you’d also have the derivative $f_1’(f_2(t))f_2’(t)=0.$ We are just applying the same logic to  $c_1f_1+c_2f_2.$ It just happens that differntiation is linear, so if a set of functions is not independent, then their derivatives are also not independent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see the distinction now. How do I resolve this question, should I delete?

Comment: @MrStormy83 No, preferably you shouldn’t delete it. If you want, you can write an answer yourself and accept it, or you can edit the question to say it’s resolved in the comments. Or just doing nothing is all right as well, I think.